# Generating all ways of applying a function to a single element with lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

This question is based on to the [11th](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/11) advent of code task. It basically is a more general version of the river crossing puzzle, you can go up and down floors while carrying one or two items each step. The goal is to bring up all items to the 4th floor.
This is fairly straightforward to solve with an A* search but finding the neighboring states is somewhat annoying.

When solving the puzzle originally I just created masks for all items on the current floor and then used the list monad to generate the combinations - slow and awkward but it works. I figured that there would be an elegant solution using lenses, though.

An easy solution could use a function that returns all options of moving a single item from floor x to floor y. Is there a way to get all combinations of applying a function to a single element using lenses? i.e. `f 1 2 [(1, 0), (1, 2)] = [[(2, 0) (1, 2)], [(1, 0), (2, 2)]]`

---

For the sake of reference, this is the best I could come up with so far, slightly simplified:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Set (fromList, Set)

type GenFloor = Int
type ChipFloor = Int
type State = [(GenFloor, ChipFloor)]

neighborStates :: Int -> State -> Set State
neighborStates currentFloor state = finalize $ createStatesTowards =<< [pred, succ]
  where
    createStatesTowards direction = traverseOf (traverse . both) (moveTowards direction) state
    moveTowards direction i
      | i == currentFloor = [direction i, i]
      | otherwise         = [i]

    finalize = fromList . map sort . filter valid
    valid = (&&) <$> validCarry <*> validFloors
    validCarry = (`elem` [1..2]) . carryCount 
    carryCount = length . filter (uncurry (/=)) . zip state
    validFloors = allOf (traverse . each) (`elem` [1..4])
```

Comment: This seems like a code review request, unless I'm missing the question here

Comment: My actual question was _"Is there a way to get all combinations of applying a function to single elements using lenses? i.e. f 1 2 [(1, 0), (1, 2)] = [[(2, 0) (1, 2)], [(1, 0), (2, 2)]]"_. Should I emphasize that in some way?

Comment: I probably just need to read more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An easy solution could use a function that returns all options of moving a single item from floor x to floor y. Is there a way to get all combinations of applying a function to a single element using lenses? i.e. `f 1 2 [(1, 0), (1, 2)] = [[(2, 0) (1, 2)], [(1, 0), (2, 2)]]`

[`holesOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:holesOf) can do that. Quoting the relevant simplified signature from the documentation:

> ```
> holesOf :: Traversal' s a -> s -> [Pretext' (->) a s]
> ```

Given a traversal, `holesOf` will generate a list of contexts focused on each element targeted by the traversal. `peeks` from [`Control.Comonad.Store`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad-Store.html) can then be used to, from each context, modify the focused target and recreate the surrounding structure:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Comonad.Store

-- allMoves :: Int -> Int -> State -> [State]
allMoves :: (Traversable t, Eq a) => a -> a -> t (a, b) -> [t (a, b)]
allMoves src dst its = peeks (changeFloor src dst) <$> holesOf traverse its
    where
    -- changeFloor :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
    changeFloor src dst = over both (\x -> if x == src then dst else x)
```

```
GHCi> allMoves 1 2 [(1,0),(1,2)]
[[(2,0),(1,2)],[(1,0),(2,2)]]
```

Comment: That's really cool although I think I might have to study up on category theory to fully appreciate what's happening here. I think it would be possible to change both fields with `map (peek dst) . holesOf (traverse . both . filter (== src))` as well. Sadly this solution is REALLY slow. Like, 80-100 times slower than my previous two. Still happy that it is possible at all, though!

Comment: @Taren (1) "I think it would be possible to change both fields with [...] as well" -- Either with that, or by changing `changeFloor` to your favourite spelling of `set (both . filtered (== src)) dst`. (2) "Sadly this solution is REALLY slow" -- Just to be sure: are you compiling with `-O2`? I have just done a few tests (outside of the context of your original problem) which suggest `-O2` can speed up this `peeks`/`holesOf` combo by ~100x; that might make it competitive with your other solution, if you weren't using it yet.